# SQLCipher with custom options

Tags: c++, sqlite, sqlcipher

I’m using sqlcipher to encrypt sqlite db using custom parameters such as,

```
PRAGMA cipher_page_size = 1024;
PRAGMA kdf_iter = 16000;
PRAGMA cipher_hmac_algorithm = HMAC_SHA512;
PRAGMA cipher_kdf_algorithm = PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA512;
```

These parameters are set up using graphycal interface of DBBrowser (SQLCipher) under Win with a specific password, and the resulting DB will be used in Raspberry let say.

[image]

I’m developing a C++ app to open the DB and query it. The result is that: file is not a database.

Went back to my Ubuntu vm and I’ve installed sqlcipher from apt. I also installed sqlitebrowser.

From the first executing pragmas and opening the db file gives the same error, from sqlitebrowser setting custom params on GUI, I’m able to open it.

What’s wrong with my steps? So what are correct steps to set custom config at command line to query the DB?
I think that this will help a lot for my C++ app too.

Comment: ANOTHER TEST

Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> attach database '2388v0_enc.sqlite' as db key 'mysecretkey'
...> ;
sqlite> PRAGMA db.cipher_page_size = 1024;
sqlite> pragma db.kdf_iter=16000;
sqlite> .tables
Error: out of memory
sqlite> pragma db.cipher_hmac_algorithm = 'HMAC_SHA512'
...> ;
sqlite> pragma db.HMAC_SHA512 = 'PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA512'
...> ;
sqlite> .tables
Error: out of memory

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add all relevant information? Comments do not support formatting, are difficult to read, and might easily get lost.